# How to find and remove duplicate objects in a collection using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, duplicates

I have a simple class representing an object. It has 5 properties (a date, 2 decimals, an integer and a string). I have a collection class, derived from `CollectionBase`, which is a container class for holding multiple objects from my first class.

My question is, I want to remove duplicate objects (e.g. objects that have the same date, same decimals, same integers and same string). Is there a LINQ query I can write to find and remove duplicates? Or find them at the very least?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove duplicates using the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) operator.

There are two overloads - one uses the default equality comparer for your type (which for a custom type will call the `Equals()` method on the type). The second allows you to supply your own equality comparer. They both return a *new sequence* representing your original set without duplicates. **Neither overload actually modifies your initial collection - they both return a new sequence that excludes duplicates.**.

If you want to just find the duplicates, you can use `GroupBy` to do so:

```
var groupsWithDups = list.GroupBy( x => new { A = x.A, B = x.B, ... }, x => x ) 
                         .Where( g => g.Count() > 1 );
```

To remove duplicates from something like an `IList<>` you could do:

```
yourList.RemoveAll( yourList.Except( yourList.Distinct() ) );
```

Comment: Will this remove them from my collection or only from the LINQ Query?

Comment: LINQ extension methods create new sets of items, your original collection will remain untouched.

Answer (score 5):

If your simple class uses `Equals` in a manner that satisfies your requirements then you can use the Distinct method

```
var col = ...;
var noDupes = col.Distinct();
```

If not then you will need to provide an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>` which compares values in the way you desire.  For example (null problems ignored for brevity)

```
public class MyTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType> {
  public bool Equals(MyType left, MyType right) {
    return left.Name == right.Name;
  }
  public int GetHashCode(MyType type) {
    return 42;
  }
}

var noDupes = col.Distinct(new MyTypeComparer());
```

Note the use of a constant for `GetHashCode` is intentional.  Without knowing intimate details about the semantics of `MyType` it is impossible to write an efficient and correct hashing function.  In lieu of an efficient hashing function I used a constant which is correct irrespective of the semantics of the type.

Comment: Will this remove them from my collection though? Or just the LINQ query?

Comment: @icemanind it will return a new collection which has no duplicates.  It will not modify a collection in place.

Comment: Excellent and best practice answer