# linq to xml check for duplicates, any equals

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have xml file

```
<Nodes>
   <Node> one </Node>
   <Node> two </Node>
   <Node> three </Node>
</Nodes>
```

inside method I'm receving list of nodes to append into file, so I want to check is there duplicates

```
public static void AppendToXmlFile(List<string> passedNodes)
{
    bool duplicates = passedNodes.Any(x=>x.Equals(doc.Element("Nodes")
                                 .Descendants("Node")
                                 .Select(a=>a.Value))); 
...
}

this query always returns false.
```

Comment: what is the data in `passedNodes`??

Comment: list of strings, one, five, six, nine, ...

Comment: answer in this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811464/how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing element `x` of `passedNodes` with the whole enumerable returned by `Select`. They are never equal, hence always false. You should really be looking for intersection of two lists instead:

```
bool duplicates = doc.Element("Nodes")
                     .Descendants("Node")
                     .Select(a=>a.Value)
                     .Intersect(passedNodes)
                     .Any();
```

Answer (score 2):

Any() will return true if the collection has any items.

To achieve what you want you can do this.

```
var duplicates = passedNodes.Descendants("Node").GroupBy(node=>node.Value).Any(grp=>grp.Count()>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Select` inside the `Any` returns a `IEnumerable`. This will never be equal to `x` (a string). Try with this

```
bool duplicates = passedNodes.Any(x => doc.Element("Nodes")
                             .Descendants("Node")
                             .Where(a => a.Value == x)
                             .Any());
```