# How to get required collection in my LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a table in my database.

```
`tblCustomers`
    - CustomerId 
    - CustomerName
```

Now my need is to get all the customers grouped by `CustomerName` but at least there should  more than one occurrence of the `customername`.

Like if there are 10 Customers with `name = "ABC"`, get them into one array but 1 `customer` with `name = "XYZ"`(Only one record with this name) Don't get this.

This is what I was thinking

```
var query = (from c in entities.tblCustomers
group c.CustomerName into cust 
//where cust.Key.Count >=2  (how to get this)
select ABC()
{
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get duplicate items from a list using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811464/how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be like this:

```
from c in entities.tblCustomers
group c by c.CustomerName into cust 
where cust.Count() > 1
select cust.Key
```

It equivalent to SQL [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) Clause.

Answer (score 2):

With method operators, it would be like this:

```
entities.tblCustomers
    .GroupBy(c => c.CustomerName)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grp => grp.Key);
```