# Replace Duplicates with unique string in Dictionary<string,list<object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<ParametersDetails>`. Parameters and ParametersDetails class is like  -

```
public class ParameterDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter> Parameters{get;set;}
   }
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }      
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
   }
```

I want ParameterDetails list should not contain any parameter with duplicate name. If any duplicate parameter name found I want to replace the name with Parametername+ parameterDetails name from the dictionary.
I can do it by traversing items and then modify items but I want to do it with lesser code.
The problem is how to traverse and find duplicates from list ..?
Is it possible in Linq?

What I am doing right now - I have taken all the parameters in 1 list and find out duplicates

```
var hasDupes = dflist.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name })
               .Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any()).ToArray();
```

Next, I am selecting the item from List

```
parameterdetails.Select(x => x.Parameters.Where(p => p.Name == dupeList.Key.ToString())).ToList();
```

Now I don't want to loop through ParameterDetials List to modify the items.
Is any easier way?

Ex- 
I am having 2 items in ParameterDetails like -

```
ParameterDetails:
[
{
 name: "test1",
 Parameters:[
{
"Name":"param1",
"Type":"paramtype1",
"Value":"value1",
"AccountName":"accname1"
},
{
"Name":"param2",
"Type":"paramtype2",
"Value":"value2",
"AccountName":"accname2"
}]
},
{
 name: "test2",
 Parameters:[
{
"Name":"param1",
"Type":"paramtype11",
"Value":"value11",
"AccountName":"accname11"
},
{
"Name":"param2",
"Type":"paramtype22",
"Value":"value22",
"AccountName":"accname22"
}]
}]
```

If I am having param1 as a duplicate name so in that I want to replace it as "param1+test2" so that it will be unique.

Comment: What is the key?

Comment: Certainly. Can you show us what you've already tried and where your *specific* issue is?

Comment: duplicate across all lists or within each list? If the second, Why not have a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Parameter>>` where the key of the inner dictionary is the parameter name?

Comment: Please see the code I have modified it

Comment: `yourCollection.Select(dicItem => { //put code here to check if item exists etc and return anonymous object that has key and Parameter property }).ToDictionary(x => x.AnonymousKey, x => x.Parameter);`

Comment: I don't understand this. Where in your code is the dictionary? If you want to "replace the name with Parametername+ ParameterDetails", then all duplicates in that list get the same combination of Parametername+ ParameterDetails, so they are again duplicates.

Comment: "Now I don't want to loop through ParameterDetials List to modify the items" Why not? A loop is the perfect tool to modify items in a collection. Don't use LIN**Q** for this, which should be used only to query something.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand exactly what you want to solve. I proposed a solution for find duplicates and to get unique values in a List. Can you show more code or be more specific, give example? Where is the dictionary?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am looking for better way to do this.

Comment: @CryogenicNeo example added in question

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 Actually, I do understand what you want to do, but I don't understand which lists store what... I have answered you in almost general. I have used what I understand to try to solve your problem and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yo find they duplicated items in a list you can use `LINQ`, this is the code using it:

```
var duplicates = dflist.GroupBy(s => s) .SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1));
```

That code will return all duplicated items in `dflist`. If you want to select all object that have an unique attribute value, you can use this code line:

```
var withoutNameDuplicates = dflist.GroupBy(s => s.Name).Select(grp => group.First());
```

Then you can change the objects `Name` attribute to the duplicated objects by, using this code:

```
var nameChangedDuplicates  = duplicates.Select( s => {s.Name = s.Name + "something"; }).ToList();
```

If you only want to get all the items from the list without duplicates, you can apply  `Dinstinct()` method to `dflist`, that method will return an `IEnumerable<T>` result:

```
var withoutDuplicates = dflist.Distinct();
```

And, if you want to return a `List<T>` instead `IEnumerable<T>`, you must use `ToList()` method like this:

```
var withoutDuplicates = dflist.Distinct().ToList();
```

You can get more information about it in these pages:

[c# - How to get duplicate items from a list using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3811464/9621052)

[Enumerable.DistinctMethod (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)

[C# - Update all objects in a collection using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/399073/9621052)

Comment: I don't have entire item as duplicate I have only name duplicate from Parameters