# Using LINQ to get all object with the same value property?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items like this:

```
Item1: Id=1, Name="name1"
Item2: Id=2, Name="name1"
Item3: Id=3, Name="Test2"
```

What I want to perform is to get reduced list like this:

```
Item1: Id=1, Name="name1"
Item2: Id=2, Name="name1"
```

So basically I want to have items that have the same value of given property.
So all the items that have the same value of given property.

I have tried to Group them but I don't know what to do next.

```
items.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Edit to explain.

It seams that I did not understand the question. The Answer is expected but there is already a solution here:

[Right answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811464/how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: May I ask how many items do you intend to have i that list?

Comment: Is your example result list correct? Shouldn't the second item be `Item2: Id=2, Name="Test2"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get duplicate items from a list using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811464/how-to-get-duplicate-items-from-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: Your edited explanation is still a bit mysterious. The items Id=4 and 5 also have the same name. Why are they excluded?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You are right its my fault, misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Given you post a Right answer link perhaps self vote to close as duplicate here instead of accepting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this input ...

```
Item1: Id=1, Name="name1"
Item2: Id=2, Name="name1"
Item3: Id=3, Name="name3"
Item4: Id=4, Name="Test2"
Item5: Id=5, Name="name1"
Item6: Id=6, Name="name3"
```

... this gets all the items occurring more than once:

```
var result = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)        // Group by name
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)   // Select only groups having duplicates
    .SelectMany(g => g);         // Ungroup (flatten) the groups
```

Result:

```
Item1: Id=1, Name="name1"
Item2: Id=2, Name="name1"
Item5: Id=5, Name="name1"
Item3: Id=3, Name="name3"
Item6: Id=6, Name="name3"
```

... this gets all the items occurring more than once and renumbers them

```
var result = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)        // Group by name
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)   // Select only groups having duplicates
    .SelectMany(g => g)          // Ungroup (flatten) the groups
    .Select((x, i) => new Item { Id = i + 1, Name = x.Name });
```

Result:

```
Item1: Id=1, Name="name1"
Item2: Id=2, Name="name1"
Item3: Id=3, Name="name1"
Item4: Id=4, Name="name3"
Item5: Id=5, Name="name3"
```

Note that `Select` has an overload providing a zero-based index.

```
Select<TSource,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,TResult>)
```

However, your example input is too simplistic, therefore it is difficult to say what you expect to happen in more complex cases.

If you want entries with a specific name:

```
string specificName = "name1";
var result = items
    .Where(x => x.Name == specificName);
```

Answer (score 3):

Group items by Name, then pick first item from each group to store into reduced list:

```
var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```